# Importar excel a python con el nombre incompleto

Tags: python, excel, pandas, importación

Necesito importar el excel que tiene el siguiente nombre,
"informacion2021-03-24-05-12-41"
Pero necesito hacerlo solo usando la primera parte "informacion2021-03-24".
Es decir nunca usar "-05-12-41" para importarlo.

Comment: Agregar un primer intento del cual se puedan puntualizar dudas.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes,  recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio, también lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Recuerda agregar lo que has intentado y explicar el problema puntual que tienes con tu código. Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/479020/edit) cuantas veces sea necesario

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crearte una lista de todos los archivos que estén en una ruta específica. Luego haces un bucle en la lista hasta localizar el string que empieza exactamente según tu cadena y entonces abrir ese archivo:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

archivo_que_busco = 'informacion2021-03-24'
miruta = 'D:\Temp' #ruta donde está el archivo
archivos = [f for f in listdir(miruta) if isfile(join(miruta, f))] #lista que contiene todos los archivos

for archivo in archivos:
    if archivo[:len(archivo_que_busco)] == archivo_que_busco:
        mi_archivo = miruta + "\\" + archivo
        break
    else:
        continue

print(mi_archivo)

# Ahora la variable mi_archivo contiene la ruta completa del archivo que quieres.
# Solo necesitas el resto de código para abrirlo
```

En mi caso este código retorna `D:\Temp\informacion2021-03-24-05-12-41.xlsx`